# SqlDependency Not firing on SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldependency

SqlDependency is not firing on database change. I have enabled database broker. When I insert manually from the dn using insert statement followed by 
`ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ENABLE_BROKER` the action is hit. What could be the problem?

```
void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    //or you can also check => if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert) , if you want notification only for inserted record
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
        sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;

        //from here we will send notification message to client
        var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
        //re-register notification
        RegisterNotification(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)` method registered? Can you add code?

Comment: Did you enable SQL dependency? SqlDependency.Start("connection string", "sql server service broker queue");

Comment: i enabled my sqlDepedancy like this  string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConString"].ConnectionString; SqlDependency.Start(con);

Comment: how can i create "sql server service broker queue"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: still not working